# Section of Objective C code is being "skipped" by Xcode without error

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I'm running into an issue where the Xcode 5.1.1 is "skipping over" a section of my code. I've put in `NSLog` debug markers and I can see that it's running through `Debug a`, not `Debug b`, but runs `Debug c` and following. I'm getting no errors and the app runs fine in the simulator except for not having the skipped code. I'm not sure what is wrong here since there are no errors or problems per se, so I'm having a difficult time searching for answers. What little I turned up didn't seem applicable to my issue.

The first section loads the first 4 .jpg's in the mainBundle directory and then converts and scales them for UIImage use. This part works fine. I use the same code to then load the first 10 .png icons from the same mainBundle directory. This is what gets skipped. I've included both the preceding working code and the following "skipped" code below.

```
    NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
    NSString *imageFileName;
    int i=0;
    _profileImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"", @"", @"", @"", nil];


    for (NSURL *fileURL in enumerator) {
        [fileURL getResourceValue:&imageFileName forKey:NSURLNameKey error:nil];

        NSNumber *isDirectory;
        [fileURL getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:nil];

        if (i<4){
            if ([imageFileName hasSuffix:@"en.jpg"]){
                NSURL *fqImageFileName = [NSURL URLWithString:imageFileName relativeToURL:bundleURL];
                [_profileImages replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:fqImageFileName];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    //convert image file name into image binary and scale

    for (int j=0; j< _profileImages.count; j++){
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_profileImages[j]];
        UIImage *myimageRaw = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        CGSize imageSize = myimageRaw.size;
        float imageHeight = imageSize.height;
        UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData scale:imageHeight/284];
        [_profileImages replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:myimage];
    }

    NSString *iconFileName;
    int k=0;
    _profileIcons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"", @"", @"", @"",  @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", nil];

    NSLog(@"Debug a"); //last location code executes

    for (NSURL *fileURL in enumerator) {

        NSLog(@"Debug b"); //not executing

        [fileURL getResourceValue:&iconFileName forKey:NSURLNameKey error:nil];

        NSNumber *isDirectory;
        [fileURL getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:nil];


        if (k<10){
            if ([iconFileName hasSuffix:@"-128.png"]){
                NSURL *fqIconFileName = [NSURL URLWithString:iconFileName relativeToURL:bundleURL];
                [_profileIcons replaceObjectAtIndex:k withObject:fqIconFileName];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Debug c"); //resumes execution
```

**Edit**
ok. So I got it working. But I'm not sure I understand why. It looks like I left a key part of the code out for you all. Enumerator is declared as:

```
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:bundleURL
                                          includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey]
                                                             options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                        errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error)
                                         {
                                             if (error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"[Error] %@ (%@)", error, url);
                                                 return NO;
                                             }

                                             return YES;
                                         }];
```

When I declared another instance of NSDirectoryEnumerator as "enumerator2" with exactly the same declaration it worked. I figured I should be able to use the same instance since I'm looking in the same directory for both set of files. So why can't I use the same instance for both? Is there a better way to make this work than creating new instances every time I need to iterate a the same directory?

Comment: What is `enumerator` and where is it setup? If it's `nil` or empty, the `for` loop won't run.

Comment: BTW - this has nothing to do with Xcode. Xcode is simply your (fancy) editor. It is not involved in the running of the code.

Comment: enumerator needs to be a non-empty array for debug b to run.  If it is, it will run, if it isn't it won't.  NSLog enumerator and find out.

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger to watch the values and control flow.

Comment: Print log at Debug a `NSLog(@"%d", [enumerator count])`

Comment: ok. So I got it working. But I'm not sure I understand why. It looks like I left a key part of the code out for you all. Enumerator is declared as:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit, the problem is simple - enumerator can only be enumerated once.

From the docs for `NSEnumerator` (the base class of `NSDirectoryEnumerator`):

> You send `nextObject` repeatedly to a newly created `NSEnumerator` object to have it return the next object in the original collection. When the collection is exhausted, `nil` is returned. You cannot “reset” an enumerator after it has exhausted its collection. To enumerate a collection again, you need a new enumerator.

Creating a 2nd enumerator, as you did, is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

> So why can't I use the same instance for both?

Because an enumerator inherently contains state -- the whole point of an enumerator is that it remembers how far along you are in the collection being enumerated. Once you reach the end, the enumerator is done. To enumerate through the collection again you need a new enumerator.

Besides that, it looks like you're mixing an enumerator with "fast enumeration." I'm not sure if that's valid or not, but either way you might get closer to what you want (and simplify your code too) by using fast enumeration over a collection. Instead of fetching an enumerator from the file manager, fetch the contents of the directory:

```
NSArray *contents = contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:bundleURL 
                  includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey]
                                     options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                       error:&error
```

Since `contents` is an array, not an enumerator, you can reuse it as many times as you like in your loops:

```
for (NSURL *fileURL in contents) {
    //...
}
//...
for (NSURL *fileURL in contents) {
    //...
}
```